# Displaying only failed status in Microsoft Azure Logic App runs in dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-dashboard

[image]

In the following snapshot taken from Azure Dashboard, I am wondering how we can display only the logic application runs with Failed Status. Right now it is Running, but it can be Succeeded or Failed. I am interested in displaying only the runs with Failed status. If anyone know anything about it, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the filter Failed from the dropdown as below,

[image]

Comment: No I mean we need to display these runs on Azure Dashboards and we cannot do something like this on Dashboard. On Dashboard it shows all the results. If it has been that easy, I would not have asked it here.

Comment: you can get it from the appinsights and then display on a dashboard